# Jquery: Replace a part of each attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

The given Html is:

```
<li><span onclick="delete('abc123')" class="save option">....</span></li>
<li><span onclick="delete('xyz987')" class="save option">....</span></li>
```

I want to replace all the "delete" with "save" but with the given id like 'abc123'. The result should look like this:

```
<li><span onclick="save('abc123')" class="save option">....</span></li>
<li><span onclick="save('xyz987')" class="save option">....</span></li>
```

I tried a lot, but it wont work because i onyl want to change delete to save without touching the id´s inside the ('')

SOLUTION:

Thanks to @Amin Jafari for the Solution-Link:

```
$('span[onclick]').attr('onclick', function(i, v){
   return v.replace(/delete/g, 'save');
});
```

Comment: `onclick` is not an attribute, it's an event! and also `delete()` is not a value it's a function returning a value, therefore you must unbind the default function and bind a new function to that event, called save.

Comment: @AminJafari `onclick` *is* an attribute, defining an event handler.

Comment: Do not use attribute-based event handlers with jQuery. Using jQuery to attach the events is more flexible and keeps the registration and event code together. Then this problem just vanishes as you will have full control over turning the handlers on and off from the jQuery code.

Comment: That "duplicate" is actually a terrible solution (except the part that suggest you do not do it this way at all), as this is an XY problem, but now this question is closed I will throw away my alternate I was posting and move on...